# How would I change this JNA Hook to listen to a specific key versus all keys?

Tags: java, winapi, hook, jna, keyboardinterrupt

I am currently trying to implement a global key listener for users to interact with a bot while it does it's work. For example escape to exit, F1 to pause, ect.
This code works but it works for EVERY key entered, I'm in the process of self teaching JNA but I do not understand where this code does specific actions and how to change these actions/inputs to differentiate them.

```
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HINSTANCE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HOOKPROC;

public class MainTestKeyHook {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HOOKPROC hookProc = new HOOKPROC_bg();
        HINSTANCE hInst = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);

        User32.HHOOK hHook = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInst, 0);
        if (hHook == null)
            return;
        User32.MSG msg = new User32.MSG();
        System.err.println("Please press any key ....");
        while (true) {
            User32.INSTANCE.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0);
        }   
    }
}

class HOOKPROC_bg implements HOOKPROC {

    public HOOKPROC_bg() {
    }

    public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
        System.err.println("callback bbbnhkilhjkibh nCode: " + nCode);
        return new LRESULT(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work. If a user wants to dismiss a modal dialog in any given application by pressing the ESC key, they'll exit your application along the way. If a user wants to open the help system in any given application by pressing the F1 key, they'll inadvertently pause your application. This is will not produce a reliable solution. You'll have to go back to the drawing board and contrive a better scheme.

Comment: Since the bot has the potential to mess up and possibly cause harm I'm ok with killing the whole application right now while I'm working on its functionality. Once the other systems are made and tested I can make something more elegant. Also I'm not using modals or jframe as of right now.

Comment: You don't appear to understand, that a low-level keyboard hook monitors *all* input for *any* application. Interacting with any application on the same desktop will thus (inadvertently) control your application. The hook doesn't (and really cannot) filter input.

Comment: No I understand that but while running this bot no other interactions should happen with the user on any applications other than stopping the bot with escape as the bot will be using robot class for mouse and keyboard control. Even if it is bad I do want to learn this low level  stuff anyways, this isn't for work or a grade or anything so "fail more, learn more"!

Comment: If you don't care about bricking your system, why not simply call [RegisterHotKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx)? After all, you do want to register a system-wide hot key, and that's what the API does. Added bonus: You can define modifiers, which would otherwise be pretty complex to implement in a low-level keyboard hook.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is information on the Windows API low level keyboard hook.

Your callback is a `LowLevelKeyboardProc` callback, the documentation for which can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The documentation reveals that the `LPARAM` passed to the callback is actually a pointer to a [`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT` structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644967.aspx). The member `vkCode` of the structure contains the virtual key code for the key which was pressed. See the full list of [virtual keycodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes).

Luckily, since you're already using the `jna-platform` package, you can use the existing type mappings. I suggest you follow what the JNA [demo application for global keyhooks](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/ea9de70cb73ca0794120666e8ed9794d88ea5c81/contrib/w32keyhook/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/KeyHook.java) does:

```
/* ... */
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.LowLevelKeyboardProc;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;

public class MainTestKeyHook {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        HINSTANCE moduleHandle = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
        
        HHOOK hookHandle;
        LowLevelKeyboardProc keyboardHook = new LowLevelKeyboardProc() {
            @Override
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT info) {
                // LowLevelKeyboardProc docs: "If nCode is less than zero, the hook
                // procedure must pass the message to the CallNextHookEx function
                // without further processing and should return the value returned
                // by CallNextHookEx."
                
                if (nCode >= 0) {
                    switch (wParam.intValue()) {
                        // alternatively WM_KEYUP and WM_SYSKEYUP
                        case WinUser.WM_KEYDOWN:
                        case WinUser.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                            handleKeyDown(info.vkCode);
                    }
                }
                
                Pointer ptr = info.getPointer();
                long peer = Pointer.nativeValue(ptr);
                return User32.INSTANCE.CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, new LPARAM(peer));
            }
        };
        
        hookHandle = User32.INSTANCE.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, keyboardHook, moduleHandle, 0);
        if (hookHandle == null)
            return;
        
        System.out.println("Please press any key ...");
        
        int result;
        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while ((result = User32.INSTANCE.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) {
            if (result == -1) {
                System.err.println("error in GetMessage");
                break;
            }
            
            User32.INSTANCE.TranslateMessage(msg);
            User32.INSTANCE.DispatchMessage(msg);
        }
        
        User32.INSTANCE.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);
    }
    
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/inputdev/virtual-key-codes
    private static final int VK_F1 = 0x70;
    
    public static void handleKeyDown(int vkCode) {
        System.out.println("Key = " + vkCode");
        if (vkCode == VK_F1) {
            System.out.println("F1 pressed!");
        }
    }
}
```

You should notice that this example calls and returns the value of `CallNextHookEx`. From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> If nCode is less than zero, the hook procedure must return the value returned by [CallNextHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974(v=vs.85).aspx).
>
> If nCode is greater than or equal to zero, and the hook procedure did not process the message, it is highly recommended that you call [CallNextHookEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644974(v=vs.85).aspx) and return the value it returns; otherwise, other applications that have installed [WH_KEYBOARD_LL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks#wh_keyboard_ll) hooks will not receive hook notifications and may behave incorrectly as a result. If the hook procedure processed the message, it may return a nonzero value to prevent the system from passing the message to the rest of the hook chain or the target window procedure.

As the last sentence says, you can return a nonzero value if the key matched whichever keys you want to intercept to prevent that key event from reaching the target window. Be careful with this though, as you might accidentally block keyboard input from yourself :-)

I would additionally suggest that you read the Windows API docs article [Hooks overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winmsg/about-hooks).